# Sorted post-condition doesn't hold

Tags: dafny

What I want to do in the method is simply to overwrite the previous array and fill it with number that are sorted, however dafny says that the post-condition does not hold and I can't for the life of me figure out why. 
I'm guessing I need to add some invariant to the loop but since they are checked before entering the loop I don't know how to put a valid invariant.

```
method sort2(a : array<int>)
modifies a;
requires a != null && a.Length >= 2;
ensures sorted2(a[..]);
{
  var i := a.Length - 1;
  while (i >= 0)
  decreases i
 {
     a[i] := i;
     i := i - 1;
 }
}

predicate sorted2(s: seq<int>)
{
    forall i :: 1 <= i < |s| ==> s[i] >= s[i-1]
}
```

My previous attempt was just to reinitialize a but dafny apparently doesn't allow that inside methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need a loop invariant in order to prove this program correct.

See Section 6 of the [Dafny Tutorial](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorial) for a general introduction to loop invariants and how to come up with them.

In this case, a good loop invariant will be something like `sorted(a[i+1..])`, which says that the part of the array after index `i` is sorted. That way, when the loop terminates and `i` is zero, you'll know that the whole array is sorted.

You will also need one or two more loop invariants describing bounds on `i` and the elements of the array itself.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I finally solved it. 
I needed to add 3 invariants:
      invariant -1 <= i <= a.Length - 1
      invariant a[i+1] == 0
      invariant sorted2(a[i+1..])

I redid it so that it fills the array with zeros as that seemed easier than filling it with indexes.

Thanks a ton for your help!